# Validation on formtastic nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic

I have a one-to-many association in my code, like this:

```
class Second < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :firsts
end
class First < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :second
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :second
end
```

In my erb for First, I have:

```
<%= f.input :one_field, :label => false %>
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :second do |cp_f| %>
    <%= cp_f.input :another_field, :as => :string, :label => "another field" %>
<%= end %>
```

The form correctly populates the data in the nested table.

I need to put some validation in the controller, and I'd like to point the user to the field where the error occurred. If I write an error like this:

```
errors.add :one_field, "This is wrong"
```

This works no problem and puts the error on the page right by the field. But I'd like to do the same thing for the nested field, like maybe:

```
errors.add :second.another_field, "Another wrong one"
```

But I get an error:

```
undefined method `another_field' for :second:Symbol
```

Is there a way to put an error on the nested field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was accessing the errors member of First. What I needed was:

```
second.errors.add :another_field, "Another wrong one"
```